# how can I imapsync from mailserver to my local machine

Tags: imap, email-server, imapsync

How can I use imapsync to fetch all the emails from the mailserver to my laptop? (with hierarchy of folders and all)?

Do I have to have a mailserver setup on the other end too?

Comment: And simply selecting [equivalent](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/imap-synchronization#w_disk-space-usage) option of synchronizing all messages and folders from your e-mail client  is in-sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMAPsync does IMAP to IMAP synchronization, as it states on it's [website](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/), which means you would need an IMAP server on the receiving end as well. It also lists http://offlineimap.org/ as an alternative without that requirement.

Comment: Use [imap-backup](https://github.com/joeyates/imap-backup).